# Diagonalizability in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, matrices

Give an example of a matrix $A\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ that is not diagonalizable, but A is diagonalizable viewed as a matrix over the field of complex numbers $\mathbb{C}.$

Comment: For the latter part, am I looking for a complex unitary matrix?

Comment: Try to look at a rotation matrix

Comment: Should probably make that title relevant to the question...

Comment: As you wish... $\left[\begin{array}{cc} 0 & \pi \\ -\pi & 0\end{array}\right]$.

Comment: @LordSoth What?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Are you religious by chance?

Comment: @Trancot What does that have to do with me removing some unnecessary part of the title?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial $x^2+1$ of $\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$ is irreducible over $\mathbb R[x]$ but not over $\mathbb C[x].$

Comment: @Sigur: What are the eigenvalues?

Comment: I like this one because $A$ is similar to a diagonal matrix if and only if $A$ has $n$ linearly independent vectors, so this means that your matrix has no eigenvectors in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @SugataAdhya, sorry. My fault. I need more coffee.. lol

Comment: Coffee sounds good right now...

Comment: @Sigur What kind of coffee do you have? Mine's fair trade Indonesian.

Comment: @Trancot, I've Brazilian coffee.

Answer (score 8):

You just need to write down a real matrix with distinct complex (non-real) eigenvalues.  Once you've found a $2 \times 2$ example, you can form an example of any size $n \times n$ for $n \ge 2$ by considering an appropriate block diagonal matrix.

Comment: +1 This is a good way to think about the problem.  It echoes the fact that polynomials in $\Bbb R$ can be reducible only to quadratics, but in $\Bbb C$ they can be reduced to linear factors.  When you diagonalize a matrix, the eigenvalues are on the diagonal.